# Puppeteer in NodeJS reports 'Error: Node is either not visible or not an HTMLElement'

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm using 'puppeteer' for NodeJS to test a specific website.  It seems to work fine in most case, but some places it reports:

> Error: Node is either not visible or not an HTMLElement

The following code picks a link that in both cases is off the screen.

The first link works fine, while the second link fails.

What is the difference?
Both links are off the screen.

Any help appreciated,
Cheers, :)

#### Example code

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const initialPage = 'https://website.com/path';
const selectors = [
    'div[id$="-bVMpYP"] article a',
    'div[id$="-KcazEUq"] article a'
];

(async () => {
    let selector, handles, handle;
    const width=1024, height=1600;
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ 
        headless: false, 
        defaultViewport: { width, height } 
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({ width, height});
    page.setUserAgent('UA-TEST');

    // Load first page
    let stat = await page.goto(initialPage, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});

    // Click on selector 1 - works ok
    selector = selectors[0];
    await page.waitForSelector(selector);
    handles = await page.$$(selector);
    handle = handles[12]
    console.log('Clicking on: ', await page.evaluate(el => el.href, handle));
    await handle.click();  // OK
    
    // Click that selector 2 - fails
    selector = selectors[1];
    await page.waitForSelector(selector);
    handles = await page.$$(selector);
    handle = handles[12]
    console.log('Clicking on: ', await page.evaluate(el => el.href, handle));
    await handle.click();  // Error: Node is either not visible or not an HTMLElement

})();
```

I'm trying to emulate the behaviour of a real user clicking around the site, which is why I use `.click()`, and not `.goto()`, since the `a` tags have `onclick` events.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('div[id$="-KcazEUq"] article a')` returns an empty nodelist — there doesn't seem to be such collection of articles (tried in non-headless Chrome)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First and foremost, your `defaultViewport` object that you pass to [`puppeteer.launch()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#puppeteerlaunchoptions) has no keys, only values.

You need to change this to:

```
'defaultViewport' : { 'width' : width, 'height' : height }
```

The same goes for the object you pass to [`page.setViewport()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetviewportviewport).

You need to change this line of code to:

```
await page.setViewport( { 'width' : width, 'height' : height } );
```

Third, the function [`page.setUserAgent()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetuseragentuseragent) returns a [`promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), so you need to [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) this function:

```
await page.setUserAgent( 'UA-TEST' );
```

Furthermore, you forgot to add a semicolon after `handle = handles[12]`.

You should change this to:

```
handle = handles[12];
```

Additionally, you are not waiting for the navigation to finish ([`page.waitForNavigation()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornavigationoptions)) after clicking the first link.

After clicking the first link, you should add:

```
await page.waitForNavigation();
```

I've noticed that the second page sometimes hangs on navigation, so you might find it useful to increase the default navigation timeout ([`page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetdefaultnavigationtimeouttimeout)):

```
page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout( 90000 );
```

Once again, you forgot to add a semicolon after `handle = handles[12]`, so this needs to be changed to:

```
handle = handles[12];
```

It's important to note that you are using the wrong selector for your second link that you are clicking.

Your original selector was attempting to select elements that were only visible to `xs` *extra small* screens (mobile phones).

You need to gather an array of links that are visible to your viewport that you specified.

Therefore, you need to change the second selector to:

```
div[id$="-KcazEUq"] article .dfo-widget-sm a
```

You should wait for the navigation to finish after clicking your second link as well:

```
await page.waitForNavigation();
```

Finally, you might also want to close the browser ([`browser.close()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#browserclose)) after you are done with your program:

```
await browser.close();
```

> **Note:** You might also want to look into [handling `unhandledRejection` errors](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_unhandledrejection).

---

**Here is the final solution:**

```
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require( 'puppeteer' );

const initialPage = 'https://statsregnskapet.dfo.no/departementer';

const selectors = [
    'div[id$="-bVMpYP"] article a',
    'div[id$="-KcazEUq"] article .dfo-widget-sm a'
];

( async () =>
{
    let selector;
    let handles;
    let handle;

    const width = 1024;
    const height = 1600;

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(
    {
        'defaultViewport' : { 'width' : width, 'height' : height }
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout( 90000 );

    await page.setViewport( { 'width' : width, 'height' : height } );

    await page.setUserAgent( 'UA-TEST' );

    // Load first page

    let stat = await page.goto( initialPage, { 'waitUntil' : 'domcontentloaded' } );

    // Click on selector 1 - works ok

    selector = selectors[0];
    await page.waitForSelector( selector );
    handles = await page.$$( selector );
    handle = handles[12];
    console.log( 'Clicking on: ', await page.evaluate( el => el.href, handle ) );
    await handle.click();  // OK

    await page.waitForNavigation();

    // Click that selector 2 - fails

    selector = selectors[1];
    await page.waitForSelector( selector );
    handles = await page.$$( selector );
    handle = handles[12];
    console.log( 'Clicking on: ', await page.evaluate( el => el.href, handle ) );
    await handle.click();

    await page.waitForNavigation();

    await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Thank you! The mising .dfo-widget-sm caused the hickups! And thank you for the other tips as well. It was a scaled down test script, and I obviously didn't pay enough attention it all.  (However, the width and height initialisation followed the ECMA 2015 notation, and should be right. :-)

Answer (score 83):

Instead of

```js
await button.click();
```

do this:

```js
await button.evaluate(b => b.click());
```

This tells the browser to run the JavaScript [`HTMLElement.click()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) method on the given element, which will fire a [`click` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event) on that element even if it's hidden, off-screen or covered by a different element, whereas `button.click()` uses Puppeteer's [`ElementHandle.click()`](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.elementhandle.click/) which

1. [scrolls the page](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/b5e6474374ae6a88fc73cdb1a9906764c2ac5d70/src/common/JSHandle.ts#L497) until the element is in view
2. [gets](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/b5e6474374ae6a88fc73cdb1a9906764c2ac5d70/src/common/JSHandle.ts#L498) the bounding box of the element (this step [is](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/b5e6474374ae6a88fc73cdb1a9906764c2ac5d70/src/common/JSHandle.ts#L417-L419) [where](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/DOM/#method-getContentQuads) [the error](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/b5e6474374ae6a88fc73cdb1a9906764c2ac5d70/src/common/JSHandle.ts#L423-L424) happens) and calculates the screen *x* and *y* pixel coordinates of the middle of that box
3. [moves](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/b5e6474374ae6a88fc73cdb1a9906764c2ac5d70/src/common/Input.ts#L419-L421) the virtual mouse to those coordinates and sets the mouse to "down" then back to "up", which triggers a click event on the element under the mouse

Comment: Okay, this fixed my problem too.  What kind of dark magic is it?

Comment: @Billy [`Page.click()`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&show=api-elementhandleclickoptions) clicks in a different way than clicking [with JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) (which is the alternative I suggested). It scrolls the element into view before clicking it but [apparently that can fail](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/6462#issuecomment-717163409) and I also see that up until 18 days ago `Page.click()` possibly had a race condition ([fixed in 7097](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/pull/7097)), maybe that's related.

Comment: The crazy thing is that this works, but using something like "await (await page.$(selector)).click()" doesn't. I guess even the .click() function is different from the evaluate e.click version

Comment: `let x = await page.$(selector); await x.click()` and `await (await page.$(selector)).click()` are the exact same thing. I explained in my comment the difference between `.click()` and `.evaluate(e => e.click())`

Answer (score 10):

For anyone still having trouble this worked for me:

`await page.evaluate(()=>document.querySelector('#sign-in-btn').click())`

Basically just get the element in a different way, then click it.

The reason I had to do this was because I was trying to click a button in a notification window which sits outside the rest of the app (and Chrome seemed to think it was invisible even if it was not).

Answer (score 8):

I know I’m late to the party but I discovered an edge case that gave me a lot of grief, and this thread, so figured I’d post my findings.

The culprit:
CSS

```css
scroll-behavior: smooth
```

If you have this you will have a bad time.

The solution:

```js
await page.addStyleTag({ content: "{scroll-behavior: auto !important;}" });
```

Hope this helps some of you.

Comment: I think you're missing the selector? eg `* {scroll-behavior: auto !important;}`

Answer (score 4):

My way

```
async function getVisibleHandle(selector, page) {

    const elements = await page.$$(selector);

    let hasVisibleElement = false,
        visibleElement = '';

    if (!elements.length) {
        return [hasVisibleElement, visibleElement];
    }

    let i = 0;
    for (let element of elements) {
        const isVisibleHandle = await page.evaluateHandle((e) => {
            const style = window.getComputedStyle(e);
            return (style && style.display !== 'none' &&
                style.visibility !== 'hidden' && style.opacity !== '0');
        }, element);
        var visible = await isVisibleHandle.jsonValue();
        const box = await element.boxModel();
        if (visible && box) {
            hasVisibleElement = true;
            visibleElement = elements[i];
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }

    return [hasVisibleElement, visibleElement];
}
```

Usage

```
let selector = "a[href='https://example.com/']";

let visibleHandle = await getVisibleHandle(selector, page);

if (visibleHandle[1]) {

   await Promise.all([
     visibleHandle[1].click(),
     page.waitForNavigation()
   ]);
}
```