# How can I click display:none element with puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, chromium, puppeteer

I want to click an element which `display` property is `none`.
How can I do this?

**Code:**

```js
page.click(".foo");
```

Comment: I don't know puppeteer but can't you just set its `display` to `block`? https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/2514#issuecomment-387467169

Comment: I would question why you would want to click on it, since `display: none;` implies it's inaccessible (eg. it's removed from the accessibility tree).

Comment: The link I want to click is normaly display:none, and it will be display:block by some actions like moov mouse to near the link whitch position is different by user because they custom design. And page.$() doesn't work for element with display:none.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Puppeteer in NodeJS reports 'Error: Node is either not visible or not an HTMLElement'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51857070/puppeteer-in-nodejs-reports-error-node-is-either-not-visible-or-not-an-htmlele) (particularly the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66537619/6243352) which is identical to the [accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55907070/6243352))

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the JavaScript [`click`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) function. This function will trigger the elements click event and does not care about whether the element is visible or not.

You need to use [`page.evaluate`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.14.0/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) to execute it inside the page.

**Example:**

```js
await page.evaluate(() => {
  document.querySelector('.foo').click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is still actual, did not worked for me using: await page.evaluate(() => { document.querySelector('.foo').click(); });

After spending at least half day, I made a small trick with changing CSS 'display' property to 'inherit', click() an element, and revert CSS 'display' back to original.

```
  let inputCheckBox = await document.querySelector("input[type='checkbox']");

  const cssDisplay = inputCheckBox.style.display;
  if (!cssDisplay || 'none' === cssDisplay) {
     inputCheckBox.style.display = 'inherit';
  }

  await inputCheckBox.click();

  if (cssDisplay !== inputCheckBox.style.display) {
     inputCheckBox.style.display = cssDisplay;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A variation on Thomas's answer using $eval for a more compact code.

```
await page.$eval('.foo', el => el.click())
```