# Javascript Puppeteer Error: Node is either not clickable or not an HTMLElement

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

If I try to click an element like this I get an error:

```
const handle = await page.$('.days-label.col-md-12.desktop div:nth-child(1)');
await handle.click();
```

However if I click it like this it works:

```
await page.$eval('.days-label.col-md-12.desktop div:nth-child(1)', el => el.click());
```

I tried fixing it by waiting for selector and navigation, but it's still the same error:

```
await page.waitForSelector('.days-label.col-md-12.desktop div:nth-child(1)');
const handle = await page.$('.days-label.col-md-12.desktop div:nth-child(1)');
await Promise.all([
    page.waitForNavigation(),
    handle.click(),
]);
```

Comment: Why not use the one that works? This behavior is [known](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66537619/6243352).

Answer (score 0):

[`waitForSelector()`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v13.0.0&show=api-pagewaitforselectorselector-options) returns `<Promise<?ElementHandle>>`:

```
const handle = await page.waitForSelector(
  '.days-label.col-md-12.desktop div:nth-child(1)'
)
await Promise.all([
    page.waitForNavigation(),
    handle.click(),
])
```

Answer (score 0):

To fire a "true" js click event, use this..

```
handle.evaluate((h)=>{h.click()})
```

.. instead of ..

```
handle.click()
```

..wghich launches '[pupeteer's click](https://pub.dev/documentation/puppeteer/latest/puppeteer/ElementHandle/click.html)' so to speak, which performers several actions to, probably, simulate user behavior, but seems less reliable.